# std::remove_reference clarification with code snippet

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand how to use the std::remove_reference functionality in type_traits.
This is the piece of code that I made

```
template <class T>
class example {
public:
    T some_int;
    example(T inty) : some_int(inty){std::cout << "constructor called!" << "\n";}
    ~example(){std::cout << "destructor called!" << "\n";}
};

template <class T>
// return a value, hence return a copy of the object
auto function(T ptr_object) -> typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*ptr_object)>::type{
    ptr_object -> some_int = 69;
    return *ptr_object;
}

int main(){
    example<int> classy(20);
    example<int> *ptr = &classy;
    auto hello = function<decltype(ptr)>(ptr);
    std::cout << hello.some_int << std::endl;
}
```

so this code compiles successfully however this is the output

```
constructor called!
69
destructor called!
destructor called!
```

My aim is to return a copy of the object (and not a reference) therefore in my calculations, once i call the return in the function it should call also the constructor of the object, but this does not happen.
Plus it calls the destructor 2 times. Can someone help me understand what I am getting wrong?

Comment: When tracking constructors/destructor, don't forget move/copy constructors.

Comment: yes but technically the return would call the normal constuctor and not the copy constructor right? I also tried calling the function without assigning it to hello but I get the same behaviour

Comment: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42701221df8d940c) with copy constructor tracked too.

Comment: *" the return would call the normal constuctor "* How `return *ptr_object;` might call `example(int inty)`?

Comment: you are right my brain collapsed but now I have come round. Thank you very much also for the demo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return a copy of the object, that creates a new object, which is what you want.
So one destructor is the for the copy, and one is for the original.
In other words your code works, but you can't see the copy constructor, add the line

```
    example(const example& cp) : some_int(cp.some_int){std::cout << "copy constructor called!" << "\n";}
```

And the output is

```
constructor called!
copy constructor called!
69
destructor called!
destructor called!
```

By the way, your code looks a little clunky, but maybe that's the point?
The alternative would be ...

```
template <class T>
T function(T* ptr_object) {
    ptr_object -> some_int = 69;
    return *ptr_object;
}
```

Which is more concise

EDIT: I just noticed that @Jarod42 beat me to it (again)

Comment: yep, but i appreciate your work ;)